# finding replacement for resistor labeled as fuse in schematic

Tags: power-supply, resistors, fuses, fusible-resistor

I am trying to find a replacement for what appears to be a burned resistor in a power supply unit.  It appears to be labeled as "F3" on the PCB which is the designation for a fuse. As far as the reason for the resistor blowing up, based on other testing I am reasonably certain that a nearby MOSFET has gone bad and I have already found a replacement for this, but I need to find a replacement for the resistor.

The lead on the left goes into the circle on the PCB next to the "F3" label, hard to see due to blob of goop:

[image: blown up resistor]

Based on the orange-orange-gold-gold bands the resistor should be 3.3ohms 5% but it reads as 13MOhms so I assume it has failed (almost) open. The physical size of the resistor is: length of resistor body = 12mm, body dia = ~4mm, lead dia = 0.5mm.

[image: schematic]

Note resistor (fuse?) F3, transformer T4, and MOSFET Q10 which are also visible in PCB picture.

I have been looking for similar resistors and found some, but I am not sure about the wattage that is needed. Since this resistor appears to be functioning as a fuse I would guess that the wattage is important. I have found some similar sized ones but their wattage varies from 1/2w to 2W.

I found some information about something called fusible resistors but they seem to have different markings on them like an extra color band.

Any help or insight in to what a suitable replacement might be or what I need to search for would be helpful.

Comment: Note 13mohms is 13 milliohms which is effectively a short circuit. I gather you mean 13MOhms which is 13 million ohms which is effectively an open circuit.

Comment: yes, I will fix it, thanks

Comment: Here... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/675772/930 I am trying to compile details about identifying fusible resistors. Some manufacturers mark them using an extra color band, some don't. Finding the exakt make and model of the resistor to be repaired may actually turn out to be a major PITA. Choosing a similar size, and making sure the replacement part is really a fusible, flame-proof resistor is a good Idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick a **fusible** "safety" resistor of the same value (3.3\$\Omega\$) and tolerance (5%), and a similar physical size. It looks like a metal oxide film type. There are also wirewound types.

There will be other things (such as one or more semiconductors) that have failed in the circuit, the resistor is just a symptom and if you just replace the resistor it will fail again immediately.

Comment: Thank you. I did mention that I believe the mosfet had failed and I would replace it along with the resistor. I believe I have found a suitable replacement: [F2W3D3](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nte-electronics-inc/F2W3D3/11653545). What is strange to me it that the current resistor in the circuit does not appear to actually have the same markings as a fusible resistor (the 5th band?) and appears to be just a regular resistor, so maybe it was used to cut costs?

Comment: The extra band is not really standardized, so I wouldn't base much on that. We sourced such parts direct from the manufacturer and they did not have any special markings. That kind of MOF resistor is inherently fusible (it doesn't arc like some film resistors) but there are other characteristics (the "safety" aka "flameproof") construction that mean it shouldn't shoot out flames excessively or smoke too much and set things nearby on fire etc. when it fails due to a short.

Comment: Links to various colour coding for fusible resistors can be found in the tag wiki https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/fusible-resistor/info

Answer (score 2):

It's labeled as F because it's a fusible resistor. The schematic gives the resistance as 3.5R I think due to the amount pixels missing.